# Sending JSON with arbitrary key values using REST service (Jersey/Jackson)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson

I want to send something like this from the client to the rest service

```
jsonObj = 
{
   "info" : {
       "field1" : "val1"..
.....
       "fieldN" : "valN"..
   }
}
```

And I am not sure how can I handle this using a rest service using

```
 Jersey and Jackson in Java
```

I do not want to create a new info class with using Jackson properties with N field as they are going to change always. I just want to grab the jsonObject which is inside the jsonObject and operate on that as JsonObject.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have a root object that you are reading the result into, you could define docInfo as a `Map<String, Object>` within your jsonObj.  This will *probably* work, but I can't give it a go presently.

If you don't have a root object you can just use a `Map<String, Object>` as your root object and play with it from there.  That Map could contain other maps for nested json objects.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use a wrapper object with an embedded map, as @digitialjoel suggested. This is a concrete example:

```
class DocInfo {
    private Map<String, Object> docInfo;

    public DocInfo() {
        super();
    }

    public DocInfo(final Map<String, Object> docInfo) {
        super();
        this.docInfo = docInfo;
    }

    // Getters, setters
}

final Map<String, Object> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(4);
data.put("field1", "value1");
data.put("field2", "value2");
data.put("field3", "value3");
data.put("field4", "value4");
final DocInfo info = new DocInfo(data);
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(info);
System.out.println(json);
```

Output:

> {"docInfo":{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"}}